# event system for server request in android

Tags: android, multithreading, events

my process is:

Activity -> Some Manager -> Server Manager -> request for information from server on a runnable

how should I build the event system for this multithreading scenario so that the information will return to the activity

up until now I had a map of request ids vs. some method to invoke

I want the structure to remain the same, and I **don't** want to use AsyncTask

also how would I go about deleting the events if the activity is destroyed

thanks in advance for the answers (if you can point me to the right article it would be great also)